# var prototype = new this(); Can someone explain this statement used by John resig in his class inheritance blog?

Tags: javascript

Blog url -> http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ .

Here is the snippet.

```
var _super = this.prototype;
initializing = true;
var prototype = new this();
initializing = false;
```

I am stumped by the use of new this();

Comment: `this` is a reference to the `Class`, which is a function, which can be invoked. I hate these clunky inheritance constructs.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to see it in context. Namely:

```
Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype;

    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing = true;
    var prototype = new this();
    initializing = false;
```

Note that `extend` is a method of (i.e., function-property of) `Class`. Inside any methods, `this` refers to the object they are a method of [1]. So inside `Class.extend`, `this === Class`. Thus `new this()` is equivalent to `new Class()`.

The reasons why he's doing this are a bit strange. He's trying to set up some sort of "class hierarchy," where everything derives from `Class`, kind of like how everything in Java or C# derives from `Object`.

I wouldn't recommend this approach.

---

[1] this is only true if the method is called as a method, e.g. `Class.extend(...)`, not when it's called as a function, e.g. `var extend = Class.extend; extend(...)`.

Comment: I knd of get what you are trying to say. Thanks Domenic :)

Answer (score 1):

For Inheritance : (Taken from [here](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html))

- You cause a class to inherit using `ChildClassName.prototype = new ParentClass();`.
- You need to remember to reset the constructor property for the class
  using `ChildClassName.prototype.constructor = ChildClassName`.

Here `new this()` referred to the ParentClass being inherited & is stored in the variable **prototype**.

What happened with the **prototype** variable in the code you referred, is similar as well.

```
// Populate our constructed prototype object
Class.prototype = prototype;

// Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to really answer the question, which is about a specific piece of code, `new this()`, and not about JavaScript inheritance in general.

Comment: It does actually, I just didn't explicitly mention earlier.